# PHP Version Check Failed Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, magento-2.0

I'm using magento 2 , and I just synced my store with magento marketplace , so now If I want to enable or disable a module from Web Setup Wizard page , I get this error from the readiness check :
PHP Version Check
Your PHP version is . The required PHP version is . Hide detail

Download and install PHP from www.php.net using this PHP Documentation.

For additional assistance, contact your hosting provider.

My php version is 5.6 , I have tryed to use also 7 but still get the error and I have also set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1 , but still getting the error.. Does anyone has any ideea how to fix this ?

Comment: could you please specify the platform (OS) you are running the Magento.

Comment: not very sure about that , but I'm using GoGeek Hosting Package from siteground.. must be some linux I guess..

Comment: Possibly relevant -- this post refers to a PHP memory limit problem, but could easily refer to a PHP version problem as well: http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/152908661755/your-current-php-memory-limit-is-128m-and-other

Answer (score 1):

To me the problem does not come from your install but from the module you're trying to install.

I'm pretty sure the module provider did not specify the right PHP versions and that's why the PHP check is failing.

Try to contact the module provider to check what versions did they specify when submitting their module to the Magento Marketplace.

Comment: but when I installed the module I had no problem to do that , why getting the error now when trying to disable it ?

Answer (score 1):

if you are running in Ubuntu(Linux) then, set the Cron job that may get you out of the issue..

blow official documents may help you to solve the issue..

1. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/php-version.html
2. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-readiness.html#compman-readiness-fail

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup 2 cron jobs. Add `update/cron.php` and `bin/magento setup:cron:run` to your `crontab`, for example

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

[Reference](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

Comment: I have already setup the cron jobs , should I update them like this ?    /usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli /home/aspirede/public_html/bin/magento cron:run >/dev/null 2>&1
/usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli /home/aspirede/public_html/update/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
/usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli /home/aspirede/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >/dev/null 2>&1
/usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli /home/aspirede/public_html/bin/magento indexer:reindex >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: Yes, but you need to set up the time intervals on each line.

Answer (score 1):

I know with some installs running on plesk I had to add

`/etc/pki/tls/certs` to **open_basedir**

This can be done via the plesk admin in the application/domain php settings.  Perhaps adding this will help with upgrade or others running into readiness check issues.