# PHP Version Check Failed on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I'm having an issue with my Magento 2 , was working fine at the beggining , I've installed a few modules, and now, when I try to enable a module from Admin - System - Web Setup Wizard, I get this error:

> PHP Version Check
>
> Your PHP version is . The required PHP version is . Show detail

My php version is 5.6 so it should be good, also I have my cron jobs set up. It seems like there is an issue with the core of Magento and/or a specific module that I've installed, which affects the readiness check and due to that reason it fails.

Comment: " The required PHP version is " ??? is what? What does it do when you click "Show detail"?

Comment: Can't access it anymore.. I logged in with my magento account , synced , and now I get this message when I try to go to web setup wizard        Welcome to Magento Admin, your online store headquarters. 
To use the Magento setup wizard sign into your Admin account and navigate to System => Tools => Web Setup Wizard

Comment: here it is ` PHP Version Check
Your PHP version is . The required PHP version is . Hide detail

Download and install PHP from www.php.net using this PHP Documentation.

For additional assistance, contact your hosting provider. `

Comment: Duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115327/php-version-check-failed-magento-2/115337#115337